# preg_replace() seems to remove entire word instead of part of it

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to match a certain word and replace part of the word with certain text but leave the rest of the word intact. It is my understanding that adding parentheses to part of the regex pattern means that the pattern match within the parentheses gets replaced when you use `preg_replace()`

for testing purposes I used:

```
$text = 'batman';
echo $new_text = preg_replace('#(bat)man#', 'aqua', $text);
```

I only want 'bat' to be replaced by 'aqua' to get 'aquaman'. Instead, `$new_text` echoes 'aqua', leaving out the 'man' part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`preg_replace` replaces all the string matched by regular expression

```
$text = 'batman';
echo $new_text = preg_replace('#bat(man)#', 'aqua\\1', $text);
```

Capture `man` instead and append it to your `aqua` prefix

Another way of doing that is to use assertions:

```
$text = 'batman';
echo $new_text = preg_replace('#bat(?=man)#', 'aqua', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not use `preg_*` functions for this and just do [`str_replace()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
echo str_replace('batman', 'aquaman', $text);
```

This is simpler as a regex is not really needed in this case. Otherwise it would be with a regular expression:

```
echo $new_text = preg_replace('#bat(man)#', 'aqua\\1', $text);
```

This will substitute your `man` in after `aqua` when replacing the entire search phrase. [`preg_replace` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) replaces the entire matching portion of the pattern.

Comment: +1: You're totally right, it *is* not needed. Took me to read the question twice to see that ;)

Answer (score 2):

The way you're trying to do it, it would be more like:

```
preg_replace('#bat(man)#', 'aqua$1', $text);
```

I'd using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_replace('/bat(?=man)/', 'aqua', $text)
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/G9F4q

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are creating a capturing group, that means you can access the part matched by this group using `\1`.

you can do either what zerkms suggested or use a lookahead that does just check but not match.

```
$text = 'batman';
echo $new_text = preg_replace('#bat(?=man)#', 'aqua', $text);
```

This will match "bat" but only if it is followed by "man", and only "bat" is replaced.